# Pass a value from one function to be used in another

Tags: javascript

How can I pass the value of a user input (from a prompt) to be used in another function without my variable "input" being global?

```
function One(a){
    var input = ' ';
    input = parseInt(prompt('enter a number');
}

function Two(b){
    document.getElementById('initial').value =  input //input is user input from function One(a)
}
```

Comment: Answers depend on how you are using it. How is `Two()` called? Can One be called multiple times and Two should have different values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pass a value from one function to be used in another

**That is the work what parameter did.**

```
function One(){
  var input = ' ';
  input = parseInt(prompt('enter a number');
  return input;
}

function Two(b){
document.getElementById('initial').value =  b//input is user input from function One(a)
}

Two(One());
```

Comment: got my initial code to now work by adding the "return input" to function One(a) and then making var a = One(a) in function Two(b) and going from there. thanks to all who replied. Could of made this work by just creating a global variable called "input"...still learning the simple workings of functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
    // ALL YOUR CODE !
    var input = '';
}());
```

Wrapping your code into a self-executing function is most likely the easiest way to avoid clobbering the global object. There are of course more sophisticated approaches, like *namespacing object* and *modular programming* patterns, but just to avoid creating globals, you're fine with creating and using private scopes.

Comment: @ArunPJohny well thats why I put that comment in there.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of `One`, can you just put `Two(input);`?

Answer (score 0):

```
function One(){
var input = prompt('enter a number');
return isNaN(input) ? "Not a number" : parseInt(input);
}

function Two(){
    document.getElementById('initial').value = One();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the value from the first function, and send it as a parameter into the second:

```
function One() {
  return parseInt(prompt('enter a number'), 10);
}

function Two(input) {
  document.getElementById('initial').value = input;
}
```

Usage:

```
var inp = One();
Two(inp);
```

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: Why the downvote? I have read the question. Carefully. Several times. I suggest that you do the same.

Comment: Please explain how your answer currently addresses: "without my variable "input" being global?" - it seems you simply create another global here?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: What do you mean?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss There is no global variable, and Guffa **doesn't** make the `input` variable global. The two lines of code at the end of this answer can be used at any point in the program. So say that when a button's clicked, it needs to run function `One`, and pass its result to `Two` - that's where this code would be used - locally and only when needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about polluting the Global namespace with too many variables, but those are still "global" i.e several functions need access to them, you could put them in a single Global Object.

```
 window.myGlobals = {};
 function One(a){
 myGlobals.input = parseInt(prompt('enter a number');
 }

 function Two(b){
 document.getElementById('initial').value =  myGlobals.input //input is user input from function      One(a)
 }
```

If you are looking for function Two to have access to all the data from function One, you could create a closure. It's hard to know without more information on what you're trying ot achieve here.